# I cannot read a stream using Promise in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following scenario:

**getStream** returns a stream from request

And I want to pass the stream to **downloadImage**, however I encounter an issue: fulfilling the promise in the 'downloadImage' it doesn't result a stream as I would have expected.

```
class ImageDownloader {

    private async getStream(imageUrl){
        const result = request(imageUrl);
        // result.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./image.jpg')); //it is a stream and it works to write it in a file
        return result;
    }

    public async downloadImage(imageUrl) {
        const imageStream = await getStream(imageUrl);
        // imageStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./image.jpg')); 
        //I receive the following error: "imageStream.pipe is not a function"

    }

}
```

How can I pass my stream asynchronously using Promises? What am I doing wrong?

Note: I simplified the methods for this example

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure that `request` returns a stream (that is not thenable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you are marking `getStream` as `async` when you do not use `await` inside the method. You also need to use `this` when calling class methods (e.g. `this.getStream(...)`).

It looks like you're trying to write a method that downloads an image (using the stream API) and returns a promise, this is how I would do it:

```
class ImageDownloader {
    private getStream(imageUrl) {
        return request.get(imageUrl);
    }

    public downloadImage(imageUrl) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.getStream(imageUrl)
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./image.jpg'))
                .on('finish', resolve)
                .on('error', reject);
        });
    }
}
```

And then you can consume it:

```
const downloader = new ImageDownloader();
await downloader.downloadImage('http://host.com/image.jpg');
```

This answer assumes you're using the [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) module.

Comment: is there a way downloadImage can return a Promise<ReadStream> ? I want to pass it further in the stack for easier readability? And then I will writeStream

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to wrap the stream in a promise, a stream is already a data structure for performing async operations, why wouldn't you just pass the stream around?